# AttachTo IE browser using Watin and Powershell

Tags: powershell, watin

I am having problems using AttachTo with Powershell. I searched, but can't find any Powershell example that uses AttachTo.

This doesn't work:
    $ie2 = $ie.AttachToIE([watin.core.Find]::ByTitle("Task Selection"))

I guess I am not sure of the syntax. The .NET uses  which doesn't work in PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ie = (New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | ? {
        $_.Name -eq 'Windows Internet Explorer' -and
        $_.LocationName -eq 'Task Selection'
      }
```

Comment: Thanks-that worked. I still have no idea why it is losing the connection, but at least I can get it back.